# Reverse enginner python code to find it's input

Tags: python, xor

I have a python code that produces some output.

```
e = [97, 71, 86, 115, 98, 71, 56, 61]
i=0
z=[]
while i < len(e):
    z += [e[i] ^ e[((i+1) % len(e))]]
    i = i+1
print(z)
```

`z` prints an list after computing the values from `e`. Now let's say I know values of list `z` and don't know `e`. How would i find elements of list `e`.

Comment: Simplest example of impossibility: if `e` contained a single element, `z` will be `[0]`, no matter what that element was.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is not injective. That means that more than one input list will get the same output list. For example for a given list `e` and any value b, `[i ^ b for i in e]` will give the same output list.

Said differently, and assuming that the lists only contain byte values, for a given result, you have 256 possible inputs. This is because once you know the first element, you can get all the others.

Of course if the list can contain 16 bits values, you get 65636 possibilities, and so on and so forth...

Comment: You got 100 extra possibilities there :-)